# Problem with defining series type for combochart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I'm currently working on a little project that imports the content of a JSON to Google Sheets and then creates a combochart with the given data. I want to format three datasets as bars and one as a line. However no matter how I define the different series types i always end up with one bar and three lines.

See code below (note that the variable lastRow is hardcoded in this instance but differs in the "real" code)

```
 let diagramm = sheet.newChart()
.asComboChart()
.addRange(sheet.getRange(3,2,lastRow - 3,1))
.addRange(sheet.getRange(3,16,lastRow - 3,1))
.addRange(sheet.getRange(3,15,lastRow - 3,1))
.addRange(sheet.getRange(3,14,lastRow - 3,1))
.addRange(sheet.getRange(3,17,lastRow - 3,1))
.setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
.setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
.setNumHeaders(-1)
.setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
.setOption("bubble.stroke", "#000000")
.setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
.setOption("legend.position", "right")
.setOption("legend.alignment", "center")
.setStacked()
.setOption("title", "Compression Days By Customer")
.setOption("annotations.domain.textStyle.color", "#808080")
.setOption("textStyle.color", "#000000")
.setOption("legend.textStyle.color", "#1a1a1a")
.setOption("titleTextStyle.color", "#757575")
.setOption("titleTextStyle.alignment", "center")
.setOption("titleTextStyle.bold", true)
.setOption("annotations.total.textStyle.color", "#808080")
.setOption("hAxis.textStyle.color", "#000000")
.setOption("vAxis.0.formatOptions.source", "none")
.setOption("vAxis.0.textStyle.color", "#000000")
.setOption("vAxis.0.ticks",[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
.setOption("vAxis.1.formatOptions.source", "none")
.setOption("vAxis.1.ticks",[25,50,75,100,125,150])
.setOption("vAxis.1.textStyle.color", "#000000")

.setOption("series.0.targetAxisIndex", 0)
.setOption("series.0.color", "#ff0000")
.setOption("series.0.labelInLegend", "CD gt 5 %")
.setOption("series.0.type", "ColumnChart")
  
.setOption("series.1.targetAxisIndex", 0)
.setOption("series.1.color", "#f0ff00")
.setOption("series.1.labelInLegend", "CD 1-5 %")
.setOption("series.1.type", "ColumnChart")
  
.setOption("series.2.targetAxisIndex", 0)
.setOption("series.2.color", "#0be52c")
.setOption("series.2.labelInLegend", "CD eq 0 %")
.setOption("series.2.type", "ColumnChart")
  
.setOption("series.3.targetAxisIndex", 1)
.setOption("series.3.color", "#146DF6")
.setOption("series.3.labelInLegend", "Count of Lines")
.setOption("series.3.type", "LineChart")

.setPosition(lastRow +1 , 1, 2, 17)
.setOption("height", 500)
.setOption("width", 1700)
.build();
sheet.insertChart(diagramm);
```

If there is anything else I should provide please just ask.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you get and an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Rafa,
thanks for your reply!
Here is the current outcome: https://imgur.com/a/ZRXpJyN
Here is the desired outcome: https://imgur.com/a/mzkklky

Thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Can you also provide a sample sheet? Without some data it's difficult to fiddle with the code to try to get it to repro